# Cant get out of this lava!

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I landed in lava in Minecraft: pocket edition and died. I keep respawning in that lava. What do I do?

Comment: Did you land in lava when you created the world? If so I would just create a new one.

Comment: No I was in a mine shaft and accidentally landed in the lava and died. Note, I'm playing in survival mode. So, is there anyway I can stop re-spawning in the lava and dying over and over again?

Comment: Hmm that's odd. Unless MC:PE treats spawning differently, I don't see why you'd be respawning in the place you died. I haven't played pocket edition though, so if there's behavior specific to that version, I don't know about it.

Comment: Thank you though:) If you figure it out or anything please tell me. It's so frustrating cx @Johonn

Comment: Which version are you using? I'm reading that 0.9.2 has respawning issues...
P.S. going to bed hope someone can help

Comment: Do you literally respawn right in a pool of lava or do you spawn above it and land in it?

Comment: sounds like someone forgot rule 1 of minecraft: NEVER dig straight down!! specialy under the spawn.  The best thing to do is to start over and never dig down again

Answer (score 1):

If you keep spawning in the lava, that world is basically done. You should just make a new world. By new world I mean just copy the world seed and restart the world.